# How to show Edit text on the bottom in Bottom-Sheet in every state?

Tags: java, android, bottom-sheet

I like to integrate comment section in Bottom-sheet. In Comment section i have recyclerView that show all comment and a EditText that situated bottom of the view. when bottom-sheet is open in Collapsed State the Edit text not showing but when State is EXPANDED the the Edit text layout is show. so i need help to show the edit text option in every state.

[This is Collapsed state Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlkA2.png)

[This is Expanded State Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxhNe.png)

I want to show Edit text in Collapsed mode just like Expended mood.

> XML Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".fragment.CommentFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:scrollingCache="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rv_main"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
                </View>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
        <View
            android:background="#B1B1B1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>




</RelativeLayout>
```

> Code

```
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final BottomSheetDialog dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE|
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        final View view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.fragment_comment, null);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        dialog.setContentView(view);
        mBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from((View) view.getParent());
        mBehavior.setPeekHeight(BottomSheetBehavior.PEEK_HEIGHT_AUTO);
        mBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);

        mBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                if (BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED == newState) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onStateChanged: STATE_EXPANDED");
                }
                if (BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED == newState) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onStateChanged: STATE_COLLAPSED");
                }

                if (BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN == newState) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onStateChanged: STATE_HIDDEN");
                    dismiss();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

            }
        });

        commentsAdapterNew = new CommentsAdapterNew(getActivity(), commentsClassList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, true);
        rvMain.setLayoutManager(mManager);
        rvMain.setAdapter(commentsAdapterNew);
        ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(rvMain, false);

        getAllComment("876");

        return dialog;
    }
```

Comment: Isn't View visiblity state's `View.GONE, View.Visible` all you need?

Comment: can you show any UI part ?

Comment: see the screenshot above @SandeepInsan

Comment: change height mach_parent to wrap_content of LinearLayout outside of your RecyclerView and check

Comment: Unfortunately that's not supported in the current behaviour. I build something similar and more powerful bottomsheet supporting lot more things but I wrote my own behavior. The BottomSheet behavior just offset the layout with respect to parent and not actually changing the height and that actually make complete sense for the purpose it is designed to serve but not ideal for every case. I would suggest to read the source code and you will get the idea how to do that.